# Adding UILabel to a custom tableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitableview

I'm trying to add a label programmatically to a custom table view cell. The app will still crash with an 'unexpectedly found nil'. I've looked into other posts here but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Please see the code for details.

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  var titleLabel: UILabel!

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 40.0, y: 2, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    addSubview(titleLabel)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

}
```

Inside the view controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    // Crashes the app with: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'
    cell.titleLabel.text = "Some text"
}
```

The custom table view class is properly assigned to the prototype cell in the storyboard.

If I change the declaration inside `MyTableViewCell` to `var titleLabel = UILabel()` and delete that line from inside the `init()` the table view will display but my label will not show up.
The code looks good to me though, any advice as to what I may be missing here?

Comment: I would make the `titleLabel` property use `let`. You can then initialize it before you call `super.init(...)`. It's best to avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals whenever you can because it allows you to get the exact error you're encountering.

Comment: Also, are you registering your cell class? You need to call `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or else that dequeue method will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did add that line now in the `viewDidLoad()`: `tableView.registerClass(ListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SongItem")` It does that trick! I've called that before with custom cells, though and didn't have a problem, but I didn't create a label as a property for the cell then. This solution has a side effect, though: Now the compiler isn't happy with my references to other labels I've added in the storyboard and get with `viewWithTag()`. Is it either programmatically or storyboard for one cell?

Comment: I usually initialise as you described but changing the initialisation of the label as you suggested will make Xcode complain about the `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` with the error: _'Property 'self.titleLabel' not initialised at super.init call'_. That's why I turned it around to this. Also, if you post as an answer, I can accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made custom cell in storyboard,so you don't need to register class for table view.And views from storyboard will call `initWithCoder` and `awakeFromNib`,please add label in these two functions.

Comment: I didn't find a method `initWithCoder()` but setting the label up in the `awakeFromNib()` did the trick. But for that I had to set the label up in the storyboard and add an IBOutlet in my custom cell class and connect it to the label in the storyboard cell. Thanks!